# Create a JSON structure from set of Java Pojo classes

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I need to create a JSON object structure from set of java pojo classes. This will provide a better understand of how the objects are structured by just looking at the Json file. I tried both  Gson  and org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper libraries. But couldn't generate all the Json tags relevant to all the fields in java pojo objects. The created json file is only having the values from the values stetted objects. I need to have all the fields of pojo objects in the Json file.

Gson

```
        Hotel hotel = new Hotel(); //This hotel object includes multiple objects and those objects also include multiple objects, lists
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(hotel);
        System.out.println(json);
```

ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("/home/Pojos.json");
```

This is the class and json response I got.

Hotel.java

```
package datatypes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Hotel {


    private     String      hotelCode;
    private     String      chainCode;
    private     String      hotelName;
    private     List<Room>  rooms           =   new ArrayList<Room>(); 
    private     List<RoomRateRestriction>   roomRateRestrictions
    =   new ArrayList<RoomRateRestriction>();


    public String getHotelCode() {
        return hotelCode;
    }
    public void setHotelCode(String hotelCode) {
        this.hotelCode = hotelCode;
    }
    public String getChainCode() {
        return chainCode;
    }
    public void setChainCode(String chainCode) {
        this.chainCode = chainCode;
    }
    public String getHotelName() {
        return hotelName;
    }
    public void setHotelName(String hotelName) {
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
    }
    public List<Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }
    public void setRooms(List<Room> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public void addRoom(Room room){
        this.rooms.add(room);
    }
    public List<RoomRateRestriction> getRoomRateRestrictions() {
        return roomRateRestrictions;
    }
    public void setRoomRateRestrictions(
            List<RoomRateRestriction> roomRateRestrictions) {
        this.roomRateRestrictions = roomRateRestrictions;
    }

    public void addRoomRateRestrictions(
            RoomRateRestriction roomRateRestriction) {
        this.roomRateRestrictions.add(roomRateRestriction);
    }
}
```

### JSON

```
   {
     "rooms":[],
     "roomRateRestrictions":[]
   }
```

Comment: share one of your model, your expected result and the output you got

Comment: And please understand that libraries don't do what you want. They do what they're documented to do. So you should read their documentation to understand how they work and what they do.

Comment: @shb I have added the pojo class and the out put I got. I expect to print all the fields of the pojo class in the JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **jackson-databind** library.
Maven dependency is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Also please find some of sample example below. Here I used Employee Object which is having nested Address object inside it.

### Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
    private int empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double salary;
    private Address address;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(int empId, String firstName, String lastName, double salary) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Employee(int empId, String firstName, String lastName, double salary, Address address) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

### Address.java

```
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String country;

    public Address() {}

    public Address(String street, String city, String state, String zip, String country) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

I converted a Sample java pojo class to Json and also JSON to pojo object back.

### JacksonConvertion.java

```
public class JacksonConvertion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        pojoToJson();
        jsonToPojo();

    }

    private static void pojoToJson() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Convert Object to json ");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            Address address = new Address("#103, 1st cross, manyta tech park", "Bengaluru", "Karnataka", "560010",
                    "India");

            Address address1 = new Address();
            address1.setCity("Bengaluru");
            address1.setState("Karnataka");
            address1.setCountry("India");

            Employee emp = new Employee(1233, "Raju", "BG", 98734.23, address1);

            mapper.writeValue(new File("staff.json"), emp);

            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(emp);
            System.out.println(jsonString);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void jsonToPojo() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Convert Json to Object ");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Employee employee = mapper.readValue(new File("staff.json"), Employee.class);

            System.out.println(employee.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(employee.getSalary());

            System.out.println(employee.getAddress().getCity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also included some of links for your reference.
[Link1](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

[Link2](https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial)

Comment: Actually what I need is to generate JSON file without setting vlaues as you did.                          ```Address address = new Address("#103, 1st cross, manyta tech park", "Bengaluru", "Karnataka", "560010",
                    "India");

            Address address1 = new Address();
            address1.setCity("Bengaluru");
            address1.setState("Karnataka");
            address1.setCountry("India");

            Employee emp = new Employee(1233, "Raju", "BG", 98734.23, address1);```

Comment: If you try to generate the JSON without setting the values then default values will be considered. For that reason only it generated the empty array structure in your JSON output.

Comment: Yes thanks, I got the out come without setting the values using jackson-databind

Answer (score 2):

Add `serializeNulls()` on `GsonBuilder()` to serialize null fields

> Configure Gson to serialize null fields. By default, Gson omits all fields that are null
>      * during serialization.

```
class Hotel {
    private String name;
    private List<Guest> guests = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(new Guest())); //you have to set a value in order to get the structure of the Guest class otherwise it will show an empty list []
    //getter setter
}

class Guest {
   private String name;
   //getter setter
}
```

Gson

```
 Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
 String json = gson.toJson(hotel);
 System.out.println(json);
```

Output

```
{  
 "name":null, 
 "guests":[  
      {  
         "name":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work fine

Add http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomfasterxmljacksondatabindjar.htm and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksondatabind205sourcesjar.htm to your library.

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class javaPojo {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(hotel);
    System.out.println("JSON = " + json);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

}

Hotel

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Hotel {

```
private     String      hotelCode;
private     String      chainCode;
private     String      hotelName;
private     List<Room>  rooms           =   new ArrayList<Room>(); 
private     List<RoomRateRestriction>   roomRateRestrictions
=   new ArrayList<RoomRateRestriction>();


public String getHotelCode() {
    return hotelCode;
}
public void setHotelCode(String hotelCode) {
    this.hotelCode = hotelCode;
}
public String getChainCode() {
    return chainCode;
}
public void setChainCode(String chainCode) {
    this.chainCode = chainCode;
}
public String getHotelName() {
    return hotelName;
}
public void setHotelName(String hotelName) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
}
public List<Room> getRooms() {
    return rooms;
}
public void setRooms(List<Room> rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

public void addRoom(Room room){
    this.rooms.add(room);
}
public List<RoomRateRestriction> getRoomRateRestrictions() {
    return roomRateRestrictions;
}
public void setRoomRateRestrictions(
        List<RoomRateRestriction> roomRateRestrictions) {
    this.roomRateRestrictions = roomRateRestrictions;
}

public void addRoomRateRestrictions(
        RoomRateRestriction roomRateRestriction) {
    this.roomRateRestrictions.add(roomRateRestriction);
}
```

}

Room

public class Room {

}

RoomRateRestriction

public class RoomRateRestriction {

}

OUTPUT  - JSON = {"hotelCode":null,"chainCode":null,"hotelName":null,"rooms":[],"roomRateRestrictions":[]}